# Question Regarding Linearly Independent And Dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Question:** Let $v_1$, $v_2$ ,$v_3$, $v_4$, $v_5$, and $v_6$ be six distinct vector of some vector space.There are 15 distinct subset consisting precisely four of these vectors.Suppose that out of this 15 subsets only {$v_1$, $v_2$ ,$v_3$, $v_4$,} and {$v_1$, $v_2$ ,$v_3$, $v_5$,} are linearly independent and rest 13 are linearly dependent.then
>
> (1) $v_6$ is zero vector .$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ [True\False]
>
> (2) $v_4$ is non zero scalar multiple of $v_5$.$~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ [True\False]

For (2) :

> **Linear Dependence Lemma**: If $(v_{1},\ldots,v_{m})$ is linearly dependent in $V$ and $v_{1}  \neq 0$, then there exists $j \in \{2,\ldots,m\}$ such that the following hold:
>
> (a) $v_{j} \in span(v_{1},\ldots,v_{j-1})$;

Since {$v_1$, $v_2$ ,$v_4$, $v_5$} is dependent By Linear Dependence Lemma

We have $ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \Rightarrow v_5=a_1 v_1+a_2 v_2 +a_3 v_4 $
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$for some scalars $a_i$ 's .where $a_3$ must be non zero.

Simillarly Since {$v_2$, $v_3$ ,$v_4$, $v_5$} is dependent By Linear Dependence Lemma

We have $ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \Rightarrow v_5=b_1 v_2+b_2 v_3 +b_3 v_4 $
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$for some scalars $b_i$ 's .where $b_3$ must be non zero.

Substracting above two equation and fact that {$v_1$, $v_2$ ,$v_3$, $v_4$,} is linearly independent we have $a_1=b_2=0$ and $a_2=b_1$ and $a_3=b_3$.

So from $v_5=a_1 v_1+a_2 v_2 +a_3 v_4 $ we have $$v_5=a_2 v_2+a_3 v_4 \tag{1}$$

Repeating same argument with different collection we have$$v_5=c_1 v_1+c_3 v_4 \tag{2}$$

Now $(1)-(2)$ and fact that $v_1 ,v_2, v_4 $ are independent we have $a_2=c_1=0$ and $a_3=c_3$.putting in $(1)$ we have $$ v_5=a_3 v_4$$

Hence (2) is correct  statement.

> (1) Is my above proof correct ?
>
> (2) Any hints for statement (1) ?